# Why public key has two parts in my secure messaging client similar to signal

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman

I am working on a Golang code similar to Signal protocol. I need to modify it. I am confused on tripartite Diffie-Hellman handshake part of code, i.e. why public key has two separate parts as compared to private key which has only one part in bytes as shown below. I can more info if needed. Thanks.

> [image]

Comment: Start with a primer on elliptic curve cryptography?

Comment: And consider using Noise if you need to design a new protocol?

Comment: Thanks a lot. A lecture on cryptography made me understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is simple. In simple words, in elliptic curve cryptography, the public key is calculated by multiplying the private key value $s$ with the base point $G$, which results a point on the elliptic curve point: $W = s \cdot G$. This point consists of has two values on the x-axis and one on y-axis if the curve is considered to be within a 2D coordinate system.

Here is a link which gives a good idea of it: [ECC with Diffie-Hellman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDXiDOJgxmg).